# How to run a batch file in cakephp2 at a certain time?

Tags: php, batch-file, cakephp-2.0

I want to run a batch file automatically in cakephp2 at midnight everyday  but I have no clue.
It would like to have some help.

Comment: Actually I want to run the bat file from cake console. So I want to make a function to do the task within the shell.

Answer (score 0):

With it being a batch file I assume you're referring to a microsoft server. Simply add a task in the task scheduler to have it run at midnight each night, as your would have a cron job complete the task in a unix system.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Cake php framework but i believe you want to use cron jobs to execute the task.
Cron Jobs can run at specific times.
Please refer to the below link for some info

http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/ 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron